# Way to get unsigned char into a std::string without reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, stdstring, reinterpret-cast

I have an unsigned char array that I need in a std::string, but my current way uses reinterpret_cast which I would like to avoid.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
unsigned char my_txt[] = {
  0x52, 0x5f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x7e, 0x29, 0x33, 0x74, 0x74, 0x73, 0x72, 0x55
}
unsigned int my_txt_len = 12;

std::string my_std_string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(my_txt), my_txt_len);
```

Comment: And why don't you like `reinterpret_cast`...?

Comment: It always seems like a hack to force a cast, I'd rather use things as is rather than force the complier to treat them as something else.

Comment: Why don't your use `char` for `my_txt`; after all, those values you posted are ASCii.  This may lead to solving other issues.

Comment: It is a generated file so I'd rather not have to further process it.

Comment: Initializing a `string` from `unsigned char*` seems pretty reasonable to me. I'm surprised anyone has an objection to wanting to do that without using a cast.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the iterator constructor:

```
std::string my_std_string(my_txt, my_txt + my_txt_len);
```

This is assuming that you want the unsigned chars to be converted to char. If you *want* them to be reinterpreted, then you should use `reinterpret_cast`. That would be perfectly clean, since what you say is exactly what is done.

In your example, though, it doesn't make any difference, because all of the values in your array are within the range `0` to `CHAR_MAX`. So it's guaranteed that those values are represented the same way in `char` as they are in `unsigned char`, and hence that reinterpreting them is the same as converting them. If you had values greater then `CHAR_MAX` then implementations are allowed to treat them differently.

Comment: What's the difference between the unsigned char's being converted to char and them being 'interpreted' as char?

Comment: @BadDesign: on most implementations it makes no difference, but on unusual architectures there could be one. The result of converting a value greater than `CHAR_MAX` to char is implementation-defined. The result of reinterpreting depends on the value representation of the types, and isn't guaranteed to be the same as converting.

Comment: Hi @steve Does the array need a trailing 0 before making a string out of it?

Comment: @Noitidart: no, the iterator constructor of `string` handles that.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried sstream?

```
     stringstream s;
     s << my_txt;

     string str_my_txt = s.str();
```

Comment: It worked great for me, not sure why you say it does not work?

Comment: Turns out I was just getting lucky, the missing terminating NULL causes ABR in some cases.  See related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889074/why-do-i-get-this-strange-output-behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
        unsigned char temp  = 200;
        char temp1[4];

        sprintf(temp1, "%d", temp);

        std::string strtemp(temp1);

        std::cout<<strtemp.c_str()<<std::endl;

        return 0;
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.